# PowerBI DAX fill columns based on columns in others tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following model:
[image]

And I would like to create a column in All Items table which contains text in
SAPBW_Items[ExtMatGroupName] if DALI_ProductFam[DALI ProductFamDescription] is empty. (All items are or in SAPBW_Items or in DALI_ProductFam but cannot be in both)

I managed to do it with the following DAX formula:

```
ProductFamily V2 = 
var _CodeItem = 'All Items'[CompanyCodeItem]
var _DALIItemSkey = LOOKUPVALUE(DALI_Items[DALI ProductFam],DALI_Items[Item_Skey_Bigint],_CodeItem)
var _DALIFamily = LOOKUPVALUE(DALI_ProductFam[DALI ProductFamDescription],DALI_ProductFam[ProductFam],_DALIItemSkey)
var _SAPFamily = LOOKUPVALUE(SAPBW_Items[ExtMatGroupName],SAPBW_Items[Item_Skey_Bigint],_CodeItem)
Return
COALESCE(_DALIFamily,_SAPFamily)
```

But as the dataset is really huge, the calculation time is a little bit slow... Is a way to improve it?
PS: 'All Items'[CompanyCodeItem], DALI_Items[DALI ProductFam] and SAPBW_Items[ExtMatGroupName] are columns of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution that work like a charm:

```
ProductFamily = RELATED( SAPBW_Items[ExtMatGroupName]) & RELATED( DALI_ProductFam[DALI ProductFamDescription])
```